# Output 2 Fields from Linq Group By

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group by the WorkGroup.GroupId property on the class

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeID {get; set;}
  public Group WorkGroup {get; set;}
}
```

However I need to output the group name property (Which could have duplicates but will be identical between the same groupid)

Something like (this of course does not work):

```
var grps = from emp in Emps
          group emp by emp.WorkGroup.GroupID into g
          select new { GroupID = g.Key, Title = g.Key.WorkGroup.GroupTitle,  Employees = g };
```

I am looking for output that would allow me to do:

```
foreach (var g in grps)
{
  Console.WriteLine(g.Title + "-" + g.GroupID);
  foreach (var e in g.Employees)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(e.EmployeeID);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just group by ID and Title:

```
var grps = 
    from emp in Emps
    group emp by new 
    { 
        GroupID = emp.WorkGroup.GroupID, 
        GroupTitle = emp.WorkGroup.GroupTitle 
    } into g
    select new 
    { 
        GroupID = g.Key.GroupID, 
        GroupTitle = g.Key.GroupTitle,  
        Employees = g
    };
```